# iMac boots at very low resolution

Tags: display, imac, resolution

I have a late 2012 27" iMac with macOS Catalina. Recently I replaced it's hard disk with an SSD and I was extremely happy with the results. However, the replacement required removing the display from the chassis & putting it back with some adhesive strips. The strips I used apparently was not strong enough. A few weeks after doing the replacement, one morning I woke up with the display glass came off of the chassis and dropped onto the keyboard on my desk, pulling its power & data cables out of the board.

I plugged the cables back and reinstalled the screen. At the first boot it started with a "snowy" screen like this [What causes “snowy” display on iMac screen after replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/478421/What+causes+%E2%80%9Csnowy%E2%80%9D+display+on+iMac+screen+after+replacement) (ifixit.com)
And since then, the computers boots only at 1280x720. I bought a new data cable and replaced it, nothing has changed. I tried resetting PRAM & SMC, I booted to ubuntu using a flash disk. None of it works.

It is an extremely weird situation. The display works. I don't have any dead pixels or anything.  But the resolution is terrible. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you have the option to try an external monitor? If you get a higher resolution there I would say that the display on the iMac was damaged when it fell.

Comment: I have ordered an external monitor and will try that

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately none.